# Data Synchronization Across Devices

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I keep my app data (in SQLite database) consistent across the users devices? He or she should see the same data regardless of device they log in from. I would like this synchronization to occur without user intervention.

Comment: Find a back end service that you like such as Azure or Firebase.  Store the data there.

Comment: what if i have a mysql database hosted on RedHat OpenShift?

Comment: Then you'll need to expose it via a web service of some kind.